# if n=myArray.Length or =myList.Count, which is a good practice to use?

Tags: c#

If we know that `int n = myArray.Length = myList.Count`

Then, when we need to use this value to represent the array/list length, which one is best to use?
e.g. do we use `var x=n*2 or var x=myArray.Length*2 or var x=myList.Count*2`

The equivalent question is like, would it be more efficient to directly use n instead of referring to the member property of an object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking the following

> If we know that a local `n == myList.Count` should I use `n` over `myList.Count` because it's potentially more efficient?

It's true that a local lookup is generally more efficient than a member access.  However the difference is very small and something I wouldn't concern myself with when writing a program.

Instead focus on writing the most readable code possible.  Don't concern yourself with micro optimizations like this because they almost certainly won't matter.  You're much more likely to find your program bottle necked at I/O, or choice of data structures than a field vs local time access difference.

Comment: I agree that in the case of n vs. list.Count the difference between a local lookup and member access would be trivial. However the same may not be true of other more complex objects, especially if we don't know how they work internally.

Comment: @DanIveson my counter argument is that if a property lookup is expensive enough that it differs significantly from a field access then it shouldn't be a property.  In either case though you shouldn't be prematurely making this optimization. Focus on readable code then let a profiler tell you what you missed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use a variable to store the length of an array, make sure that you're using a more suitable name than "n". For example, you may want to use:

```
int arrayLength = myArray.Length;
```

However, I prefer to use `myArray.Length` throughout my applications because I know exactly what it's referring to. At the end of the day, though, I suppose this is just personal preference.